# DIV stretch to height 100% in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have following layout:

4 rounded corners background and two panels (left panel and right panel) inside it.

Currently I implement the layout as follows:

Table with 9 cells:

```
top left corner    |                  | top right corner
                   |left div right div|
bottom left corner |                  | bottom right corner
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <table id="content" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="corner1.jpg" /></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="corner2.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" height="100%">
                <div id="menu" style="float: left; width: 235px; height: 445px; background-color: #660000">
                    Menu
                </div>
                <div id="mainContent" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; height: 100%; background-color: #888888">
                    Main Content
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="corner3.jpg" /></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="corner4.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to ask is how I can stretch the height of the right div to **100%** so that it equals to the height of the td (height of left div will increase according to users' action).

I have tried many ways and still cannot figure it out.Set height of div to **100%** does not work.

What should I do to acheive this? Don't use table?

PS:

The code is changed. You can paste the code into the notepad and test it in **IE**.

The code is edited again to add the **DOCTYPE**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as you already have tables for layout, I wouldn't really bother trying to do it the *"right"* way.

Just use another table.
CSS

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #menu {
            width:235px;
            height:445px;
            background-color:#660000

        }
        #mainContent {

            height:100%;
            width:auto;
            background-color:#888888
        }
        #container {
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<table id="content" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><img src="corner1.jpg"/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><img src="corner2.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="top" style="padding:0px;">
        <table id="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

            <tr>
                <td id="menu"><div>Menu</div></td>
                <td style="width:10px"></td>
                <td id="mainContent"><div>Main Content</div></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="corner3.jpg"/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><img src="corner4.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The assumption that because a table is being used, things are being done the "wrong way", is idiotic.  What if I happen to be displaying tabular data, and I want to have a cell in each row containing an element whose height I want to stretch to the full height of the cell?

Comment: @Jez the question is about a layout that already uses tables, not about displaying tabular data. I also air-quoted "right", because sometimes it isn't actually the best way to do it.

Comment: In addition Jez, the code in the question clearly is not optimal. You should be more careful before calling others idiotic.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can add a min-height to the right div equals to the value of height of the left one... it could maybe do the trick to what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You could set the position of the div to be absolute, but then of course you'd have to position it absolutely.

Comment: This worked for me. I set the position:relative value on the parent container and position:absolute on the one I wanted to stretch 100% vertically. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Or how about just using a span?

eg.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:540px; width:100%; background-color:green;">
           my name is earl!
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="height:540px; width:100%; background-color:yellow;">
            <span style="height:100%; display:inline-block; width: 100%; background-color:blue;">
                blinkers on!
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Don't worry too much about the 100% in the table elements, but rather look at the span..
The span :

```
        <span style="height:100%; display:inline-block; width: 100%; background-color:blue;">
            blinkers on!
        </span>
```

See the 'display:inline-block'? Now that is the important part.. 
I hope that this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I have used jquery and the animate call to set heights of divs, but you can set the animate speed to 0.

The example belows was for some mockups for quickly playing around with 2,3,5... block designs. The Jquery animate call is used to size the height of divs for main content, sidebar etc, ... but this may be a bit over the top for your requirement.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mock_2_ColGoldenRatio.aspx.cs" Inherits="ia._HtmlMocks.Mock_2_ColGoldenRatio" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css" >


/*normalise*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:100%;
font-style:normal ;
font-weight:normal;
border-collapse:collapse ;
border-spacing:0;
border:0;
border-width: 0px ;
text-align:left;
}
q:before,q:after
{
    content:'';
}

/*center everything using html container*/
html{
text-align: center ; 
}

/* wash with olive ; make body width max 976 px ; no margin ; relative position so other elements within */
body
{
background-color:Olive; 
width:976px; 
margin:0 auto ; 
text-align: left ; 
position: relative  ;
}

#HeaderEnc
{
background-color : Maroon ; 
}

#SearchEnc{
background-color: red ;
border-width: 0px ;
}

#MainBlogNav{
background-color:Yellow  ;
}

/* postion relative to normal flow */
#ContentEnc{
background-color: Teal  ;  
position: relative  ;
}



    #ContentSideBarA
    {
    position: absolute ; 
    background-color: #AAA ; 
    left: 62% ; 
    width: 38% ; 
    }

    #ContentMainEnc{
    position: absolute ; 
    background-color: #888; 
    left: 0% ; 
    width: 62% ; 
    }

    #ContentSideBarB{
    position:absolute ; 
    background-color : #AAA ; 
    left: 0% ; 
    width: 0px ; 
    }

    #FooterEnc{
    position: absolute ; 
    background-color: blue ; 
    left: 0 ; 
    width: 100% ; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="HeaderEnc">
    The quick brown fo jumped over the lazy dog. 
    <br />
    HeaderEnc
        <div id="SearchEnc">SearchEnc</div>        
        <div id="MainBlogNav">MainBlogNav</div>        
    </div> 

    <div id="ContentEnc">
        <div id="ContentMainEnc"><i>ContentMainEnc</i> : 
            <% Response.Write( GetContentBig()) ; %>
        </div> 

        <div id="ContentSideBarA"><i>ContentSideBarA</i> 
            <% Response.Write( GetContentSmall()) ; %>
        </div> 

        <div id="ContentSideBarB"><i>ContentSideBarB</i>
            <% /*Response.Write( GetContentMedium()) ;*/ %>
        </div>

        <i>ContentEnc-Start</i>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <i>ContentEnc-Start</i>
    </div>
    <div id="FooterEnc" >FooterEnc</div> 

</body>
</html>


<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3/jquery-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="../../Scripts/plugins/dimensions_1.2/jquery.dimensions.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<!--<script  src="../../Scripts/Common/IaCommon.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>-->

<script  type="text/javascript" >

    /*
    * ia.common 0.1.0 
    *
    */

    var ia = {}
    ia: "0.1.0";

    // gets max settings from set of elements
    var getBoundaries = function(elements) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        var maxTop = 0;
        var itemSelector = '';
        var itemHeight = 0;
        var itemPosition = {};
        var itemTop = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            itemSelector = elements[i]
            itemHeight = $(itemSelector).height();
            itemPosition = $(itemSelector).position();
            itemTop = itemPosition.top;
            maxHeight = itemHeight > maxHeight ? itemHeight : maxHeight;
            maxTop = itemTop > maxTop ? itemTop : maxTop;
        }
        return { 'maxHeight': maxHeight, 'maxTop': maxTop };
    }

    // Rets truthy  ; used by property get/set public fns
    var SetIfOk = function(val) { return val; }

    // IaPage class
    var IaPage = function(objSpec) {
        // override default page object with defaults from caller
        var that = $.extend({
            'speedFooterAnimate': 3000
            , 'speedContentAnimate': 1000
        }, objSpec || {});

        // fn to move footer, ... to correct position : inmann clearing
        that.arrangePageStructure = function() {
            boundaries = getBoundaries(this.ContentElements);
            $(this.FooterEncSelector[0]).animate({ 'top': boundaries.maxTop + boundaries.maxHeight }, this.speedContentAnimate);
            $(this.ContentEncSelector[0]).animate({ 'height': boundaries.maxHeight }, this.speedFooterAnimate);
        };
        // Ret
        return that;
    }


    var iaPage = IaPage(
    {
        'ContentEncSelector': ['#ContentEnc']
        , 'FooterEncSelector': ['#FooterEnc']
        , 'ContentElements': ['#ContentEnc', '#ContentSideBarA', '#ContentMainEnc', '#ContentSideBarB']
    }
    );

    $(function() {
        iaPage.arrangePageStructure();
    }
    );

</script>
```