# How can i set height value 100% for <aside> in container with height is not 100% of body not using tables

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="aside">
            Lorem
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Ipsum <br/> dolor <br/> sit <br/> amet <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and following CSS:

```
body { 
    padding-top:50px;
}
.aside {
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
}
.content {
    width: 670px
    float: left;
}
```

How can i set `.aside` height is 100% of `.container` if `.container` height is 100% of `.content` content. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set element (DIV/TABLE/other) height to 100% of its container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891670/how-to-set-element-div-table-other-height-to-100-of-its-container)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put your aside to absolute position and set height to 100% and set the container to relative like:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.aside {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    width: 670px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="aside">
    Lorem
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Ipsum <br/> dolor <br/> sit <br/> amet <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try** this:

```
body { 
    padding-top:50px;
}

.container {
   position: relative;
 }

.aside {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    width: 670px
    float: left;
    margin-left: 310px;
}
```